# Where should I cp oc binary to on MacOS?

Tags: macos, path, openshift, macos-sierra

In [this documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html) it says

> unpack the archive and move the oc binary to a directory on your PATH

I tried `echo $PATH` and it returns:

> bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin

Clearly there are multiple path here, which one should I move cp oc binary to?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` would be the obvious choice. That way it won't get wiped out when you update the OS.

Comment: @PaulR make it an answer please

Comment: Sure - comment convert to answer below,

Comment: FWIW. Having just relative path of just ``bin`` in ``PATH`` is probably a bad idea. You should check how that is getting in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin` would be the usual choice for user or third-party executables. That way it won't get wiped out when you update the OS.

See also: [Where do you keep your own scripts on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18682413/253056) - the question is about scripts rather than binaries, but the same logic applies.